# Change [mlab] tag description

Tags: discussion

Majority of questions with the mlab tag (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mlab) are for the Database-as-a-Service product: https://mlab.com/. Perhaps [python-mlab] can be used for Python/Matlab questions and [mlab] for the DBaaS product.

Comment: And [mongodb-mlab], [node.js-mlab], [heroku-mlab], [javascript-mlab]?  Make no sense whatsoever, we encourage users to use more than one tag.

Comment: I think you want a disambiguation. mlab alone might mean more than one thing.